# What is the time complexity of computing a Fibonacci number of at least n?

Tags: time-complexity

This is *not* the same as that classic time complexity problem about Fibonacci numbers your professor taught you in school. (That one asked for the time complexity of the *n*th Fibonacci number; I'd like the complexity of computing the Fibonacci sequence until encountering a value ≥ *n*.)

This arises in the data structure for ropes: [the Boehm et al. paper on Ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) requires us to slot subtrees (containing subropes) into slots in the array; are numbered by their Fibonacci number¹:

```
1  2  3  5  8
↑        ↑
↑        subrope
subrope
```

That is, the slot labelled "3" holds a (single) rope whose length is in [3, 5).

A various points, we have leaves of (mostly) arbitrary size, which must then be slotted into a slot; thus, we need to compute which slot it goes into.

That algorithm is (mostly) trivial to write, but in terms of the number *n*, what is the running time of `fibonacci_of_at_least(n)`?

<sub>¹I've mirrored the diagram over a vertical line from how the Boehm et al. paper represented it; I frankly find the Boehm et al. paper's representation odd from a CS perspective, where the slot 1 is almost certainly going to be index 0 in an array in an implementation, and ergo belongs on the left.)</sub>

<sub>The Boehm et al. paper mostly elides this problem: since the Fibonacci numbers we need correspond to the length of a string, we only need up to that length. 64-bits is ~100 numbers, and gets you out to exabyte string lengths. You can thus compute these in O(1) time, by just precomputing the table. However, I'm interested in the theoretically complexity.</sub>

Comment: Isn't it enough to just take the closed form for Fibonacci, and rewrite the equation?  $F_n$ is the closest integer to $\phi^n/\sqrt{5}$, hence to find $n$ s.t. $F_n \geq x$, one can compute $\log (x\times \sqrt{5})/\log \phi$, and this is ±1 the correct value.

Answer (score 5):

It is known that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n = \begin{bmatrix} F_{n+1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Using this, compute $F_1,F_2,F_4,\ldots,F_{2^m}$ until $F_{2^m} \geq n$. Then use binary search to recover the minimal Fibonacci number exceeding $n$.

Since $F_r$ grows exponentially in $r$, we have $2^m = \Theta(\log n)$ and so $m = \Theta(\log \log n)$. The algorithm thus runs in $O(\log\log n)$ steps. Each one involves calculation with numbers of size $O(\log n)$, so the overall complexity is $\tilde{O}(\log n)$.